Spectra of intersection of rings
I have found many results on the intersection of affine schemes, however I am interested in geometric interpretations of the spectrum of the intersection of rings, namely $\operatorname{Spec}S\cap S'$ for $S,S' \subseteq R$.
The toy example I was playing with was $\mathbb{Q}[x^2, x^3], \mathbb{Q}[x^2, x^5] \subseteq \mathbb{Q}[x]$ where their ring intersection is $\mathbb{Q}[x^2, x^{15}]$, which I was thinking may represent counting some multiplicity at the points of intersection of the curves $x^2=y^3$ and $x^2=y^5$.
I was also looking at the intersection of the schemes to see if I can get some interesting comparison. The intersection $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{Q}[x^2,x^3] \cap \operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Q}[x^2,x^5]$ is $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{Q}[x^2, x^3]\otimes_{\mathbb{Q}[x]}\mathbb{Q}[x^2,x^5] \cong \operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Q}[x^2, x^3, x^5]$, however this nows seems like a curve in $\mathbb{A}^3$, which wouldn't make sense. I'm not sure how to interpret this in terms of the intersection or how it may be helpful with interpreting the spectrum of intersection of rings. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Are you familiar with some category theory? In particular that the intersection is a special kind of fiber product?

I am familiar with $U\times_X V \cong U\cap V$ where $U,V \subseteq X$ are open subsets of the scheme X, and I thought this made sense: in the affine case from the algebraic perspective the tensor product will "merge", so to speak,  the common elements between the two rings by letting them pass between components of the tensor product, but I'm not sure of how to think of the intersection geometrically.

I should also clarify that in differential geometry, I understand the fibered product as two spaces being glued to where they map in the base space X. In the context of the question, may just not be seeing how to interpret the gluing between these subrings/curves

Martin is talking about fiber products / pullbacks in the category of commutative rings, not in the category of schemes; fiber products are a generalization of intersection. This means when you take the categorical dual, intersection of subrings corresponds to pushouts of schemes.

It is a pushout in the category of affine schemes which, in general, will not be a pushout in the category of schemes. This can even be seen already for the underlying topological spaces.
